# R: xts to ts, with same starting end ending values

Tags: r, date, xts

I've an xts object, that I want to transform into an ts series with same index as start and ending Points and the same frequency. But that should be as automatically as possible.

```
Lets say  "series" is an xts object and looks like this:

1997-01-01     21
1997-02-01     29
1997-03-01     8.6
1997-04-01     12.9
1997-05-01     15.3
...            ...
```

Then I want to transform it into ts:

```
y <-  na.omit(ts(series, frequency=12), start= start(series), end=end(series))
```

It doesnt work with start and end. It gives me just numbers as index for the series and not the date

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, could you also include expected output

Comment: `ts` cannot directly represent dates.  If freq = 4 or 12 it will regard the numbers as years with fraction representing months or quarters but that is it.  If you want to use dates you probably don't want to use ts.   Date class represents dates internally as days since the UNIX Epoch so you can use those as your time index if you like.

Comment: Is there a still a way to assign the month and year in the ts argument start=c(year,month) automatically from my xts series?